# Ask for and save billing information on order-pay page in Woocommerce

Tags: php, woocommerce, hook

In the WooCommerce backend, I manually create orders for over-the-phone customers and then send them the "**Customer payment page**" link so that they complete their payment.

On that page ("order-pay", with template templates/checkout/form-pay.php), I've added the following code to display the **billing form**:

```
<h3><?php _e( 'Billing details', 'woocommerce' ); ?></h3>
<?php do_action( 'woocommerce_before_checkout_billing_form', $order ); ?>
<div class="woocommerce-billing-fields__field-wrapper">
    <?php
    $fields = WC()->checkout->get_checkout_fields( 'billing' );
    foreach ( $fields as $key => $field ) {
        $field_name = $key;

        if ( is_callable( array( $order, 'get_' . $field_name ) ) ) {
            $field['value'] = $order->{"get_$field_name"}( 'edit' );
        } else {
            $field['value'] = $order->get_meta( '_' . $field_name );
        }   
        woocommerce_form_field( $key, $field, $field['value'] );
    }
    ?>

</div>
<?php do_action( 'woocommerce_after_checkout_billing_form', $order ); ?>
```

I'd like customers to be able to edit their billing info (name, email, phone, address) and **have it saved upon payment**. This is done on the "regular" checkout page using the following line but doesn't work on the order-pay endpoint.

```
$('body').trigger('update_checkout');
```

How can I validate & save those fields' values (overwriting exiting billing info) upon payment?

Answer (score 7):

This is a multi-step solution but it has been working for me.

Make sure you have copied the form-pay.php file to your child theme (yourtheme/woocommerce/checkout/form-pay.php) so you don't lose all of your work on an update.

At the top of your form-pay.php add the following two lines of code right after defined( 'ABSPATH' ) || exit;

```
$tempateURL = get_stylesheet_directory_uri();
$orderID = wc_get_order_id_by_order_key($_GET["key"]);
```

Next you will add your billing fields inside of the order_review form. I added mine just after the closing table but before the payment fields.

```
<h3><?php _e( 'Billing details', 'woocommerce' ); ?></h3>
<?php do_action( 'woocommerce_before_checkout_billing_form', $order ); ?>
<div class="woocommerce-billing-fields__field-wrapper">
    <?php
    $fields = WC()->checkout->get_checkout_fields( 'billing' );
    foreach ( $fields as $key => $field ) {
        $field_name = $key;

        if ( is_callable( array( $order, 'get_' . $field_name ) ) ) {
            $field['value'] = $order->{"get_$field_name"}( 'edit' );
        } else {
            $field['value'] = $order->get_meta( '_' . $field_name );
        }   
        woocommerce_form_field( $key, $field, $field['value'] );
    }
    ?>

</div>
```

Then create a "next" button just after the closing ?> but before the closing  of the billing details like this:

```
<div class="my-button">
    <input type="button" id="update-billing" class="button-next" value="Next">
</div>
```

It will look like this:

```
<h3><?php _e( 'Billing details', 'woocommerce' ); ?></h3>
<?php do_action( 'woocommerce_before_checkout_billing_form', $order ); ?>
<div class="woocommerce-billing-fields__field-wrapper">
    <?php
    $fields = WC()->checkout->get_checkout_fields( 'billing' );
    foreach ( $fields as $key => $field ) {
        $field_name = $key;

        if ( is_callable( array( $order, 'get_' . $field_name ) ) ) {
            $field['value'] = $order->{"get_$field_name"}( 'edit' );
        } else {
            $field['value'] = $order->get_meta( '_' . $field_name );
        }   
        woocommerce_form_field( $key, $field, $field['value'] );
    }
    ?>
    <div class="my-button">
        <input type="button" id="update-billing" class="button-next" value="Next">
    </div>
</div>
```

I created a js folder in my child theme and created a file called custom-jquery.js . 
I enqueued the new js file in my functions.php using this code:

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts',  'my_enqueue_assets' ); 
function my_enqueue_assets() {
    wp_enqueue_script( 'my-jquery', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/custom-jquery.js',"", false, false ); 
}
```

I then created a folder called woo-functions inside of the js folder and created a file called update-cart.php

I then wrote the following code:

```
<?php
    require_once(rtrim($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'], '/') . '/wp-load.php');
    print_r($_POST);
    $orderID = $_POST["orderID"];
    $firstName = $_POST["firstName"];
    $lastName = $_POST["lastName"];
    $billingCompany = $_POST["billingCompany"];
    $billingAddress_1 = $_POST["billingAddress_1"];
    $billing_city = $_POST["billing_city"];
    $billing_state = $_POST["billing_state"];
    $billing_postcode = $_POST["billing_postcode"];
    $billing_phone = $_POST["billing_phone"];
    $billing_email = $_POST["billing_email"];

    update_post_meta( $orderID, '_billing_first_name', $firstName );
    update_post_meta( $orderID, '_billing_last_name', $lastName );
    update_post_meta( $orderID, '_billing_company', $billingCompany );
    update_post_meta( $orderID, '_billing_address_1', $billingAddress_1 );
    update_post_meta( $orderID, '_billing_city', $billing_city );
    update_post_meta( $orderID, '_billing_state', $billing_state );
    update_post_meta( $orderID, '_billing_postcode', $billing_postcode );
    update_post_meta( $orderID, '_billing_phone', $billing_phone );
    update_post_meta( $orderID, '_billing_email', $billing_email );

    echo $firstName;
?>
```

I then wrote the following jquery in my custom-jquery.js file to update the information when the "next" button I created was clicked.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

$("#update-billing").on("click", function(e){
    var stylesheetURL = $("#order_review").attr("data-theme-url");
    var orderID = $("#order_review").attr("data-order-id");
    var firstName = $("#billing_first_name").val();
    var lastName = $("#billing_last_name").val();
    var billingCompany = $("#billing_company").val();
    var billingAddress_1 = $("#billing_address_1").val();
    var billing_city = $("#billing_city").val();
    var billing_state = $("#billing_state").val();
    var billing_postcode = $("#billing_postcode").val();
    var billing_phone = $("#billing_phone").val();
    var billing_email = $("#billing_email").val();

    console.log(firstName);
    $.ajax({
        method: "POST",
        url: stylesheetURL +  "/js/woo-functions/update-cart.php",
        data: {
            orderID: orderID,
            firstName: firstName,
            lastName: lastName,
            billingCompany: billingCompany,
            billingCountry: "US",
            billingAddress_1: billingAddress_1,
            billing_city: billing_city,
            billing_state: billing_state,
            billing_postcode: billing_postcode,
            billing_phone: billing_phone,
            billing_email: billing_email
        }
    })
    .done(function( msg ) {
        console.log(msg);
        $(".page-id-10 table.shop_table, .page-id-10 .the-payment-fields").slideToggle();
        $(".woocommerce-billing-fields__field-wrapper").slideToggle();
    });
});
```

I also added a .slideToggle function to hide the billing fields when the "next" button is clicked. Woocommerce dynamically adds the information to the checkout page and your normal checkout page will have the same page number. If you don't make the slideToggle function target a unique class, it will affect your normal checkout page. Because of this, I added a class of ".the-payment-fields" to the div id "payment" in the form-pay.php file.

```
<div id="payment" class="the-payment-fields">
```

When the customer clicks the "next" button it saves the data to their profile and you can see the billing information on the order.

Hope this helps!